# Spring + JPA + Maven + JSF problems with datasource configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, datasource, applicationcontext

I get the following error whenever I try to run/deploy a maven project, which I feel is properly developed. The error ..
Build Path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/apache/commons/pool/impl/Generic/ObjectPool....is found on the line

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

in my datasource-config file, which is then imported in the applicationContext.xml.
I would be grateful if anyone can help. The application is being implemented on eclipse Luna + tomcat 8,0.

Comment: Post `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Hi @LisuBB, Thanks I changed the version of org.apache.commons.dbcp in the pom xml file and it seem to work. But I still have some warnings on when trying to deploy: